# React layout with flexbox

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am a beginner with react native, and I am trying to achieve this layout:

[image]

The problem is: if I make both `flex:1` , the upper box will be always half height, but I want that it wrap its content is smaller, and grow untill half of the screen

I tried this configuration:

```
UPPER: flex: 0, flexShrink: 2
LOWER: flex: 1, flexShrink: 2
```

In this way, the upper box wraps and then grows, but does not stop at half.

I tried this configuration:

```
UPPER: flex: 0, flexGrow: 2
LOWER: flex: 1, flexGrow: 2
```

In this configuration it grows untill half, but does not wrap if smaller.

How can I implement such behaviour?

Many thanks

Comment: Flexbox has nothing to do with React.  If you provide some sample HTML and CSS for us, we could help you more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the maxHeight property to restrict height.

```
UPPER: flex: 0, maxHeight: '50%'
LOWER: flex: 1
```

StyleSheet example

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  upper: {
    flex: 0,
    maxHeight: '50%',
  },
  lower: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```